# Bit manipulation clarification in C

Tags: c, bit

i'm learning bit manipulation and i am considering a problem and would like some clarification

If given something like  `0000111111111111;`

and i want 2 functions:

*Assuming i am reading the indexes from right to left and indexes start at 1, i.e index 1-12 =1, index 13,14,15,16 = 0*

1. If i want to make it so that i remove one zero starting from the left

   - am i correct in thinking that a right shift by 1 would achieve what i want?
2. If i want to add one zero to the left so it becomes `0001111111111111`

   - how do i go about achieving this?

Comment: right-left ordering and indices starting at 1 makes my head hurt.

Answer (score 0):

> If i want to make it so that i remove one zero starting from the left
>   am i correct in thinking that a right shift by 1 would achieve what i
>   want?

**Answer:** `No`. If you `right-shift`, you are changing the number by shifting all bits by `one` **to the right** and the `least significant bit` (the one on the far right) falls off the end:

```
0000011111111111;
```

> If i want to add one zero to the left so it becomes 0001111111111111
>   how do i go about achieving this?

**Answer:** you `left-shift` and add `1`:

```
0000111111111111;   original
0001111111111110;   left-shift
0001111111111111;   +1
```